# Difference between scraper, crawler and spider in the context of Scrapy

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

Trying to read the code of Scrapy. The words *scaper*, *crawler* and *spider* are confusing. For example

```
scrapy.core.scraper
scrapy.crawler
scrapy.spiders
```

Could anyone explain the meanings and differences of these terms in the context of *Scrapy*? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Crawler** (`scrapy.crawler`) is the main entry point to Scrapy API. It provides access to all Scrapy core components, and it's used to hook extensions functionality into Scrapy.

**Scraper** (`scrapy.core.scraper`) component is responsible for parsing responses and extracting information from them. It's being run from the Engine, and it's used to run your spiders.

**`scrapy.spiders`** is a module containing base `Spider` implementation (that you use to write your spiders), together with some common spiders available out of the box (like the CrawlSpider for ruleset-based crawling, the SitemapSpider for sitemap based crawling, or XMLFeedSpider for crawling the XML feeds).

More information available on the official documentation pages:
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=crawlspider#spiders
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html?highlight=scrapy.crawler#module-scrapy.crawler

Comment: “parsing responses and extracting information”: is that spider?

Comment: Yes, scraper component is responsible for running spiders.